# Rearranging a multidimensional array (adding one dimension)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a tricky one here: there's a multidimensional array in a form like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [path] => /folder/subfolder1/
            [filename] => file1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [path] => /folder/
            [filename] => file2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [path] => /folder/subfolder2/
            [filename] => file3
        )
)
```

Now I want to rearrange it so it is mapping the given folder-structure. E.g. in this case to have

```
Array
(
    ['folder'] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [path] => /folder/
                    [filename] => file2
                )

            ['subfolder1'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [path] => /folder/subfolder1
                            [filename] => file1
                        )
                )

            ['subfolder2'] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [path] => /folder/subfolder2
                            [filename] => file3
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I've tried with array_map() and I've tried with combining [] in a foreach {} but I'm totally stuck here. And I've brooded over this so long that I'm afraid that I'm not seeing the wood for the trees anymore.

Comment: You want this to work on any depth or it's on 2 levels only ? Consider adding your attempts so we can help you and indicate where you went wrong.

Comment: You should explain more precisely what you want to do. We cant reverse engineer the array to figure out what you really want. :)

Comment: I guess he wants to nest the array by the path from the original array.

Comment: Sorry if it is too little information! Yes, I want to nest it by the ['path'] - and I'm afraid there'll be more than 2 levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for :

Let me know if you need some explanations. I felt like the recursive was explanatory enough. Of course you could use some PHP built-in functions at some point to parse your arrays, but when you have to deal with complex structure and recursion, it can be clearer to do it by yourself with some regular foreach, imo.

```
$array[0]['path'] = '/folder/';
$array[0]['filename'] = 'file1';
$array[1]['path'] = '/folder/sub1';
$array[1]['filename'] = 'file2';
$array[2]['path'] = '/folder/sub2';
$array[2]['filename'] = 'file3';
$array[3]['path'] = '/folder/sub2/sub3';
$array[3]['filename'] = 'file4';
$array[4]['path'] = '/folder/sub2/sub3';
$array[4]['filename'] = 'file5';
$array[5]['path'] = '/folder/';
$array[5]['filename'] = 'file6';

function add_element_to_folder (&$new_array, $path, $filename) {
  $folder = array_shift($path);
  if (empty($path)) {
    $new_array[$folder][] = $filename;
  } else {
    add_element_to_folder ($new_array[$folder], $path, $filename);
  }
}

$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
  $path = array_filter(explode('/', $value['path']));
  add_element_to_folder($new_array, $path, $value['filename']);
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [folder] => Array
        (
            [0] => file1
            [sub1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => file2
                )

            [sub2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => file3
                    [sub3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => file4
                            [1] => file5
                        )

                )

            [1] => file6
        )

)
```